# undefined local variable or method `link_params'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, controller

I'm working on a reddit mock-up through a tutorial. When on my localhost I am on my new page(submit new link) where I can submit a title and url.

Whenever I submitted the information, I would previously end up on a blank create view.

The tutorial is asking for us to find a way to populate our database and end up on a show view with our submitted information & also have our newly submitted information be available on our index page.

This is my attempt at editing my controller for this, but I've failed miserably:

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController

    def index
      @link = Link.all
    end

    def show
      @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
      @link = Link.new
    end

    def create
      @link = Link.new(link_params)
        if @link.save
            redirect_to @link 
        else
            render action: 'new'
        end
    end


end
```

I am getting an error that reads:

```
undefined local variable or method `link_params'
```

Any advice on how to fix this?

This is my new view:

This is new view:

```
<%= form_for(@link) do |f| %>
  <% if @link.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@link.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this link from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @link.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :url %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :url %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My show view is currently empty save for some header text:

Also, if someone had some advice on how to go about further improving my controller & views as well to get the desired result that would be appreciated, I am new & trying to learn, thanks.

Comment: Have you defined link_params in your controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a link_params method in your controller

```
def link_params
  params.require(:link).permit(:url, :title)
end
```

Comment: Should this be a private method?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. To visit my index page I should be able to just go to /links correct? How can I get my index view to show all of the submitted links though?

Comment: `@link.each do |link| link_to(link.title, link.url) end` in index.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form from browser, it hits the controller action. The form will submit some parameters which needs to be processed. Follow rails logs to see what is being returned, this is the best simple way to know and debug things.

Here in your create action, **@link = Link.new(link_params)** you are initializing Link object with link_params data, when the form is submitted check what parameter contains the hash. Parse over that hash to pass data in Link class object. You need to define `link_params` or use something like **params[:link]** after confirming from the server logs.